# Is it ever possible to render content *behind* its container's background?

Tags: css, z-index, css-position

No amount of z-index trickery, etc., will ever allow the word "foo" here to be behind a background image on the `div`, correct?

```
<div>
  <span>foo</span>
</div>
```

Or, consider this:

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b">
  <span class="x">X</span>
  <span class="y">Y</span>
</div>
```

Is it possible for `.x` to render *behind* `.a` while `.y` renders *in front of* `.a`?

I am not aware of any technique for doing so.

Note: It’d b OK if this only worked in Webkit.

Answer (score 1):

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index):

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in
>   back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
> 6. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

Notice that the children are always painted after the background of the parent element, regardless of their `z-index`. You can't get children to paint before the background, so there's really no way for you to do this with CSS.

Comment: Thanks for this. I (unfairly) asked two questions, and this clearly answers the first (and titular) question. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I appear to solve the question you have asked, please checkout this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cAZQP/1/. I made your elements in question into colored squares to make it easier to see, and spaced them slightly over each other to see the layers created.

These styles seem to work:

```
<style>

.a, .x, .y {
    position: absolute;
}
.x {
    z-index: -1;
}

</style>
```